# how can i check there is a record and get record values from the database using single result set in java?

Tags: java, sql

how can i check there is a record  and get value from the database using single resultset in java...

i'm using this code to check there is record in database or not..

then i'm get the record set values but it's not fetch the second row values...
It display one row values...
anyone give me the solution....

```
try {
    Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:mobile","","");
    String qry = "SELECT * from login";
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(qry); 
    if (rs.next()) {
        while(rs.next()) { 
            System.out.println(rs.getString("value1");
            System.out.println(rs.getString("value2");
        }     
    } else {
        System.out.println("No Records");
    }
} catch(Exception e) {  
    System.out.println(e);
}
```

Comment: Does your database contains more than one record.
Also if you want to check if there is a record in the database or not then I would modify the query to get
"select count(*) from login where login_id = 'wahtevername'"

Comment: Check [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/jdbc-sample-code.htm) example. Also make sure that there are more than 1 row in the table.

Comment: have 2 rows i checked....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

If you want to trigger whether there are records exist in database or not:

```
if (!rs.next()) 
{
    System.out.println("No Records Found");
}
else
{
    while(rs.next())
    { 
        System.out.println(rs.getString("value1");
        System.out.println(rs.getString("value2");
    }
}
```

If you don't want to trigger whether there are records exist in database or not then following will be enough:

```
while(rs.next())
{ 
    System.out.println(rs.getString("value1");
    System.out.println(rs.getString("value2");
}
```

**Update1**  Try this:

```
try
{
    pstmt = con.prepareStatement("Select * from login", ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
    rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
    if (!rs.next()) 
    {
        System.out.println("No Records Found");
    }
    else
    {
        rs.beforeFirst();
        while(rs.next())
        { 
            System.out.println(rs.getString("value1");
            System.out.println(rs.getString("value2");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @karthi try the `Update1`, I think this will work, I have tested it on my machine and it is working here, so let me know if it still doesn't works

Answer (score 1):

hi your problem is that you are using rs.next() in if condition as well as in while condition.
when you are using while loop you dont need to check if(rs.next())

using this causes you recordset's cursor to move two position further that lead you to skip the first record.

should use

```
if(!rs.isLast()){
    while(rs.next()){
        System.out.println(rs.getString("value1"));
        System.out.println(rs.getString("value2"));
    }
}
```

Comment: i got error like"java.sql.SQLException: Result set type is TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY"

Comment: got error like  "java.sql.SQLException: Result set type is TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY"  what can i do..

Comment: you can simply remove the if statement..
if of no use in your case

Answer (score 0):

The `rs.next()` method moves the cursor forward one row at a time. After you execute your query, you can immediately start iterating over the `ResultSet`; if there is no single record in your `ResultSet`, the first call to `next()` will return `false` and your `while` block is never executed.

Your current code always skips the first record in the `ResultSet`, which is most likely not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you checking if row exists?

`while(rs.next())` will automatically check and `do` if next row exist, but if you want to say something when row not exist, you should use `if(rs.isLast())`